# How do the passwords work?

Tags: cheats, street-fighter-x-mega-man

Like Mega Man 2, Street Fighter X Mega Man features a password "save" system. How does it work?

Is there a password generator or guide similar to the [ones available for Mega Man 2](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22mega+man+2%22+password+guide+OR+generator)? This is so I can effectively "load" the game with specified bosses or levels finished, and amounts of lives or E-tanks already specified.

If not, I'll take any passwords with bosses or levels finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password system for SFxMM is actually *identical* to the one from Mega Man 2!

Just swap the bosses according to this table and you can generate any password you want:

```
Fighter      Robot
---------+--------------
Blanka   | Heat Man
C. Viper | Quick Man
Ryu      | Flash Man
Urien    | Crash Man
Dhalsim  | Bubble Man
Chun-Li  | Wood Man
Rolento  | Air Man
Rose     | Metal Man
```

**SOURCE:**

- https://github.com/michaelcmartin/megaforge/blob/master/algorithms.txt
- That document describes the algo backbone of this site, which is an online Mega Man password generator:
  http://michaelcmartin.github.io/megaforge/

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the game only allows to save up to 4 tanks if you use passwords.
You can try using these passwords:

[image]

Credit goes to [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/693507-street-fighter-x-mega-man/faqs/65567)

I could not find any information on any password generator out there, but this should be enough anyway.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

B2 And E1 For airman(rolento)
D5 And D2 for bubbleman(dhalsim)
D4 and B1 for crashman(urien)
C5 And b3 for flashman(ryu)
C1 and E4 for heatman(Blanka)
B4 and E5 for metalman(rose)
C3 and D3 for Quickman(C.viper)
E2 and C4 for woodman(Chun li)
Simple To get it

A1,A2,A3,A4 and A5 for how many e tanks